# RegEx: Must have at least one number, one letter and should allow whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I need an expression that will validate against any string containing only numbers, letters and white spaces but must have at least one of each (upper and lowercase are interchangeable and allowed). It cannot contain special characters.

I try with this one, but does not contemplate whitespaces:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

Some examples of strings that need to validate:

- Street 123 [VALID]
- Street123 [VALID]
- 123Street [VALID]
- 123 Street [VALID]
- Street [INVALID]
- 123 [INVALID]

Comment: does it require at least one white space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. The positive lookahead is good, but by definition it does not advance the cursor. You need to add `.*` for a catchall if you anchor at the beginning and end of string. In addition you need to test to exclude special characters:

```js
const input = [
    'Street 123',
    'Street123',
    '123Street',
    '123 Street',
    'Street',
    '123',
    'Street@123!'
];
const regex = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*[^ a-zA-Z0-9]).*$/

input.forEach(str => {
  console.log('"' + str + '" ==> ' + regex.test(str));
});
```

Output:

```
"Street 123" ==> true
"Street123" ==> true
"123Street" ==> true
"123 Street" ==> true
"Street" ==> false
"123" ==> false
"Street@123!" ==> false
```

Explanation of exclude special characters regex:

- `(?!`...`)` - negative lookahead of:
- `.*[^ a-zA-Z0-9]` - anything followed by not allowed characters defined in a negated character class

Comment: Any questions? Does this answer your question?

Comment: You could also omit the last lookahead by just adding a space to the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+` and to prevent unnecessary backtracking, make use of contrast using negated character classes `^(?=[^\d\r\n]*[0-9])(?=[^a-zA-Z\r\n]*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$` https://regex101.com/r/NrhjFz/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird: No, removing the last lookahead and adding a space would not work, input ` ` would result in a false positive.

Comment: It would not match a space ` `. The lookahead already guarantees a char a-zA-Z and a digit, so no false positives https://regex101.com/r/QpVR26/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Ah, I was confused with "just adding a space to the character class", which did not specify where, so I interpreted it to add it to the positive lookahead. Yes, replacing `(?!.*[^ a-zA-Z0-9]).*` with `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+` should do the trick